# When Eslint parse Tsx/Ts file 'public' token, always shows 'Parsing error: Unexpected token'

Tags: typescript, eslint, tslint

i am using eslint and react, while writing public token in tsx/ts file, always show me public is unexpected token..

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it shows error because i use `babel-eslint`...just change my eslint parser to `@typescript-eslint/parser`...